# symfony serialize() returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist

Tags: symfony, serialization, symfony5

I suddenly started getting this error, after doing some Entity changes unrelated to this action

> Notice: serialize(): "questionPools" returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist

Action looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param UserProvider $userProvider
 * @param Exam $exam
 * @param ExamService $examService
 * @Route("/start/{id}", name="/start")
 */
public function startAction(UserProvider $userProvider, Exam $exam, ExamService $examService)
{
    try {
        $userExam = $examService->startExam($exam);
        $userExam->setUser($userProvider->getUser());
        $this->db()->persist($userExam);
        $this->db()->flush();
    } catch (RuntimeException $exception) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', $exception->getMessage());
        return $this->redirectToRoute('userExam/available');
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        $this->addFlash('danger', $exception->getMessage());
        return $this->redirectToRoute('userExam/available');
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('userExam/fill', ['hash' => $userExam->getHash()]);
}
```

Stack trace leads to vendor, as the error happens during the redirect.
"questionPools" is property of an `Exam` Entity:

```
/**
 * Class Exam
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ExamRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="exam",indexes={@ORM\Index(name="search_idx", columns={"start", "stop"})})
 */
class Exam implements EntityInterface
{
    // Time in minutes
    const DEFAULT_TIME = 30;
    const DEFAULT_THRESHOLD = 80;

    use IdTrait;

    /**
     * @var Collection|QuestionPool[]
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\QuestionPool",
     *     mappedBy="exam",
     *     cascade={"persist", "remove"},
     *     orphanRemoval=true,
     *     )
     */
    private Collection $questionPools;
```

`startExam(Exam $exam)` method of `ExamService` class does not change this collection, only creates an `UserExam` object based on it. It should pass this object, I don't understand why it throws some serialization error.
I thought it has something to do with caching, but I even manually deleted the /var/cache/dev directory to be sure it's not that.
For full clarity here's the stack trace:

```
ErrorException:
Notice: serialize(): &quot;questionPools&quot; returned as member variable from __sleep() but does not exist

  at W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\security-http\Firewall\ContextListener.php:178
  at Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\ContextListener->onKernelResponse(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener.php:117)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:230)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->callListeners(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.response', object(ResponseEvent))
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\EventDispatcher.php:59)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response')
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\event-dispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch(object(ResponseEvent), 'kernel.response')
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:190)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->filterResponse(object(RedirectResponse), object(Request), 1)
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:178)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\HttpKernel.php:79)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Kernel.php:195)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (W:\wamp64\www\exams\public\index.php:20)
```

Please advise, I'm really lost here. Thank you.

EntityInterface looks like this:

```
interface EntityInterface
{
    public function getId(): ?int;
}
```

And IdTrait is:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait IdTrait
{
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private int $id;

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        if (empty($this->id)) {
            return null;
        }
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

Also, the action where the redirect causing issue leads:

```
    /**
 * @param UserProvider $userProvider
 * @param Request $request
 * @param ExamService $examService
 * @param string $hash
 * @return JsonResponse|RedirectResponse|Response
 * @Route("/fill/{hash}", name="/fill")
 */
public function fillAction(
    UserProvider $userProvider,
    Request $request,
    ExamService $examService,
    string $hash
)
{
    /** @var UserExam $userExam */
    $userExam = $this->getRepo(UserExam::class)->findOneBy(['hash' => $hash]);
    if (!$userProvider->checkUser($userExam->getUser())) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Exam belongs to someone else.');
    }
    if (!$userExam->isOngoing()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('userExam/show', ['id' => $userExam->getId()]);
    }
    $form = $this->createForm(UserExamFormType::class, $userExam);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        try {
            $exam = $examService->checkExam($userExam, $form->get('finish')->isClicked());
            $this->db()->persist($exam);
            $this->db()->flush();
            $this->db()->refresh($userExam);
            if (!$userExam->isOngoing()) {
                return $this->redirectToRoute('userExam/show', ['id' => $userExam->getId()]);
            }
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', $exception->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return $this->response(
        [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'pageName' => $userExam->getExam()->getName()
        ]
    );

}
```

I'm using current version of Symfony (5.2.4) and Doctrine (2.7 ORM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented Serializable interface for Exam entity, methods looking like this:

```
public function serialize()
{
    return json_encode(['id' => $this->id]);
}

public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    $data = json_decode($serialized, true);
    $this->id = $data['id'];
}
```

It works, there is no error but imo it's only an ugly workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Working through chat we found that there needed to be the SerializationInterface per the documentation - https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#understanding-how-users-are-refreshed-from-the-session

Comment: Latest versions (just updated them today, nothing changed), AbstractEntity provided in original post (thou it's nothing special, just an ID column)

Comment: Have you tried to clear the cache with `php bin/console cache:clear`?

Comment: Yes, I even manually cleared cache (by deleting files) to be 100% sure it's not a cache problem. It happens the same in newly deployed project on other machines.

Comment: I have changed the Exam entity. Let's remove the AbstractEntity, along with changing to `private` instead of `protected` as well. I have looked at the Entities created with `php bin/console make:entity` for the relationships. Don't forget to clear the cache with the command above

Comment: I've made the changes and cleared the cache. Migrations didn't detect any changes so it seems I did it correctly, but unfortunately error is the same.
But... I use AbstractEntity for every Entity in my project. I'll try out using a Trait for ID instead of extending abstract base class in all Entities. Will get back after.

Comment: Which line in your controller specifically throws the error? The stacktrace doesn't seem to show which line in the Controller. It almost looks like there's something else in the works here

Comment: I've changed all my entities to implement EntityInterface instead of extending AbstractEntity. Error stays the same. The error happens during an execution of `redirectToRoute()`, after try-catch but before executing `fill` action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229779/discussion-between-hppycoder-and-arkadiusz-galler).